Finding a solution of the Cauchy problem using method of characteristics
I need to find a solution to this Cauchy problem with method of characteristics. How to do it?
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u(1-u)) = 0$
$u(x, 0) = u_0(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } x \leq 0, \\
1 - x & \text{if } 0 < x \leq 1, \\
0 & \text{if } x > 1.
\end{cases}
$

$u_t+(1-2u)u_x=0$, thus $$dt = \frac{dx}{1-2u}=\frac{du}{0}.$$ The last means that $u$ is constant along the charateristics. The first two combine to $x+(2u-1)t=c$. Next use these insights to check for shock and rarefication events.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + (1-2u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1-2u}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from necessarily $du=0$
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1-2c_1}$
$$x-(1-2c_1)t=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expessed on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$\boxed{u=F\big(x-(1-2u)t\big)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the initial condition).
Initial condition :
$u(x, 0) = u_0(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } x \leq 0, \\
1 - x & \text{if } 0 < x \leq 1, \\
0 & \text{if } x > 1.
\end{cases}
$
The initial condition is a piecewise function. As a consequence $F$ will be a picewise function.
Case $x \leq 0$ :
$u=1=F\big(x-(1-2u)0\big)=F(x)\quad\implies\quad F(x)=1$. The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution leading to : $\quad u(x,t)=1$.
Case $0 < x \leq 1$ :
$u=1-x=F\big(x-(1-2(1-x))0\big)=F(x)\quad\implies\quad F(x)=1-x$. The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution leading to : $\quad u=1-\big(x-(1-2u)t\big) \quad\implies\quad u=\frac{1-x+t}{1-2t}$
Case $x >1$ :
$u=0=F\big(x-(1-0)0\big)=F(x)\quad\implies\quad F(x)=0$. The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution leading to : $\quad u(x,t)=0$.
The particular solution satisfying both the PDE and the initial condition is :
$$u(x, t) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } x \leq 0, \\
\frac{1-x+t}{1-2t} & \text{if } 0 < x \leq 1, \\
0 & \text{if } x > 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Jacquelin, I can't find the words to express how grateful I am for your answer. Could you please suggest what I should read to learn how to solve such equations on my own in the future? I’m not stupid, just extremely uneducated. I tried reading the third chapter of Evans’ book, but it was too difficult for me. Is there a textbook that explains what you just did for someone who’s never encountered a differential equation before? Just point a direction for me, that's all I'm asking.

The question is ambarrassing because they are various approaches and an extensive litterature on the subject. My above answer is far to provide a full view. One can find the bases of this approach in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics. For training one can find a lot of examples of solved problems  on the StackExchange forum.
